# Oracle query that translates unix style bitwise integer

Tags: sql, oracle

These days, when we want to store multiple "options" in one column in bits, we usually do it like this:
00000101
But, there is another way where it's just stored as an integer like with unix permissions where each of the permissions options has a 1, 2, or 4 assigned to it, and any combination of these can be represented with a number from 1 to 7.

I have data that is using this second method, and I'm looking for a query that will return the matching rows given that integer from 1 to 7 (or, whatever for larger data sets).

I've built something that "works" but is ugly and I was hoping someone knew of a more elegant solution. Mine will not scale well at all.

Here's what I have:

```
select company from
(
    select 7 bit, 'ABC' company from dual union select 7 bit, 'DEF' company from dual union select 7 bit, 'GHI' company from dual
    union
    select 6 bit, 'DEF' company from dual union select 6 bit, 'GHI' company from dual
    union
    select 5 bit, 'ABC' company from dual union select 5 bit, 'GHI' company from dual
    union
    select 4 bit, 'GHI' company from dual 
    union
    select 3 bit, 'ABC' company from dual union select 3 bit, 'DEF' company from dual
    union
    select 2 bit, 'DEF' company from dual
    union
    select 1 bit, 'ABC' company from dual
) comp_bits
where bit = 5
```

Any advice?
This requires that I have 12 rows instead of just 3.

Thanks

///////////////////////////////////////////

The response from MathGuy was the correct answer. Thank you.
Here is the example rewritten using bitand:

```
with comp_bits as
(
    select 4 bit, 'GHI' company from dual 
    union
    select 2 bit, 'DEF' company from dual
    union
    select 1 bit, 'ABC' company from dual
) 
select company from comp_bits where bitand(5,bit) != 0
```

Comment: This sounds like a potentially interesting question, but I didn't understand your explanation of it. If you use integers to encode multiple yes/no attributes, you can use the `bitand` function to select those entities (rows, records) that have a given subset of attributes set to "yes", etc. But from your explanation I wasn't able to understand what, exactly, you are trying to do. For example, you say "matching rows", but you didn't say what that means. Matching what?

Comment: That is EXACTLY the answer. Thank you very much. 
Unfortunately, I can't see how to mark your response as correct. Also, comments won't let my put code here, so I'll edit this question to show how I did it with your answer.

Comment: I figured out why I was unable to mark the response from @mathguy as correct. He added it as a comment instead of an answer. If you want to respond as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't worry about marking a correct "answer" - it was really a simple hint.

Comment: Note, though, that if 5 encodes two "yes" attributes, the `!=0` condition will identify all entities that have AT LEAST ONE of those attributes set to "yes". If you want both attributes to be set to "yes", you must use a different condition: `=5`. This is not about Oracle - it's generally true regardless of language, it's a theoretical (logic) observation.

Comment: No, that's perfect. I'm looking for all records that have that have (in this example,) either the 1 or the 4 bit.
In case you're curious, my company is 3 companies that have merged together and we own a lot of network hardware. Now, downstream hardware owned by ABC and other downstream hardware owned by DEF might now connect to the same upstream hardware. We are planning on phasing out this "legacy company" data, but until we do, whether or not hardware is associated with company 1, 2, or 3 is stored in a single column. I need return all companies that an element is associated with.